# How to create a 'snow that's pile up' effect in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, sprite-kit, skscene

There are a lot of tutorials out there about how to create a rainfall and snowfall effect using `SKScene`.
I was wondering if anyone has any idea how I could create the effect of snow accumulating at the bottom of the view or on top of other view, after falling. I tried to do that but without success. Thanks you.

Comment: This repository may help you with some basic SwiftUI confetti animation - you could try to change the particle type and then ensure the particles are above a certain Y value. https://github.com/simibac/ConfettiSwiftUI

Comment: I know that repository and I love the confetti effect. You suggest me to try to modify it to keep the particles on the bottom of the screen instead to make it fade away, after some time? Thanks